# Which event triggers when UltraTabPageControl window is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I am binding UltraTabPageControl to BaseForm in infragistics(C# Windows application).

Which event triggers when i close the ultraTabPageControl window?

Obviously baseform_closing can be used but i don't need to write my code in this event as number of usercontrols binding to BaseForm is more.

I need to write a piece of code on close event of ultraTabPageControl.

Kindly let me know how can i handle close event of UltraTabPageControl.

Answer (score 1):

UltraTabControl has a `TabClosed` and `TabClosing` events.
These events are related to the closing of the UltraTab in which the UltraTabPageControl is hosted.

The event handler receives an argument of type `TabClosingEventArgs` or `TabClosedEventArgs` containing data related to this event.

Every UltraTab is recorded in the Tabs collection of the UltraTabConrol. Every UltraTab has its UltraTabPageControl

I think that these differences with the standard windows tab control are due to the presence of a 'Shared Page' where controls hosted there are visible on every UltraTabPageControl

A code example explains better the hierarchy

```
    // Call BeginUpdate to prevent the display from
    // refreshing as we add individual tabs.
    // Note: This MUST be paired with a call to
    // EndUpdate below.
    this.ultraTabControl1.BeginUpdate();

    UltraTab tabAdded;
    UltraTabsCollection tabs = this.ultraTabControl1.Tabs;

    // Add a tab to the Tabs collection
    tabAdded = tabs.Add("options", "&Options");

    // Create a new control
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Location = new Point(20,20);
    tb.Size = new Size(80, 20);

    // Add the control to the tab's tab page
    tabAdded.TabPage.Controls.Add(tb );

    // Call EndUpdate to allow the display to refresh
    this.ultraTabControl1.EndUpdate();
```

EDIT:

The order of events called by the Framework when you close the main form of your application is the following:

```
MAINFORM - FormClosing
MAINFORM - FormClosed
MAINFORM - Deactivate
MAINFORM - HandleDestroyed
CONTROL - HandleDestroyed
   .... - repeat for each control
CONTROL - Disposed
   .... - repeat for each control
MAINFORM - Disposed
```

As you can see the UltraTabControl and all of its pages should be still available when you receive the FormClosing event. The base property IsDisposed should be still false at that moment in time and thus no TabControl is 'closed'

Now I have a doubt - We are talking about a WinForms application right?

Comment: Steve thanks for the answer. But i need to write the code when the window is closed(X button or ALT+F4) which has a ultratabpagecontrol.In the base form i have form_closing event.when i close the window ,baseform_closing event triggers.In this event i need to check whether ultratabpagecontrol is closed.If closed, which active tab is closed.

Comment: Yes steve , we are talking about winforms. It was very informative the list of events you mentioned which occurs during the close event of baseform/MAINFORM. In MAINFORM_FormClosing event, i am unable to access usercontrolname.IsDisposed property..

Comment: @VikasKunte Is the UltraTabPageControl on the base or derived form?  If on the base form I would expect you to have access to it.  If on the derived form, why would you need to access it from the base form?  Is there a reason why you can't have the logic in the derived form.